# What to do to get rows respective to checked checkboxes and then write out the values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, checkbox

Hello fellow programmers,

Right now I have a webpage which displays a data-table via grid-view. This works fine. I also inserted a column of check-boxes in the beginning of the view. This works fine as well. But when I try to retrieve info from cells from the row whose respective check-box is selected, I get an empty string.

Below are the parts of my code pertinent to this problem:

.aspx:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {

        }

        //server connections and whatnot//

        OleDbCommand c0 = new OleDbCommand(sql0, myConnection);
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = c0;
        DataSet ds0 = new DataSet("Contacts");
        myAdapter.Fill(ds0);
        DataTable dt0 = new DataTable(); 
        dt0 = ds0.Tables["Contacts"];
        DataView view = new DataView();
        view.Table = dt0;
        GV0.DataSource = view;
        GV0.DataBind();

        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

.cs:

```
    /**
     * WHY U NO WORK?!
     */
    public void Dedupe(Object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        String output = "start ";
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GV0.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (cb.Checked == true)
            {
                output += row.Cells[1];
            }
        }
        Label1.Text = output;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to databind the control? I'm wondering if you are rebinding the control on postback. If so, that will prevent you from seeing any changes that were made to the control.

Comment: @rsbarro When I try to bind CheckBox1 in the PageLoad method, it says that it isn't declared within this context.

Comment: How does `GV0` get its data? I'm assuming `GV0.DataSource = something; GV0.DataBind();`? Can you post the method where that happens?

Comment: @rsbarro    DataView view = new DataView();
            view.Table = dt0;
            GV0.DataSource = view;
            GV0.DataBind();

Comment: Is that code you posted wrapped in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`? It would really be helpful if you could edit your post and give us the entire method that contains the code from your comment.

Comment: **UPDATE** I fixed my initial problem with the string being empty, but now every single cell contains System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell instead of the actual value appearing on the webpage.

Comment: @Jackery Xu: First thing you should try is to put your grid binding code in !ispostback block if you are getting selected checkboxs ids  by triggering any server side event.Second thing, change row.Cells[1] to row.Cells[1].Text otherwise you will get System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell as you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but in your foreach loop you may need to check the RowType property of the current row that you are looping over and make sure that it is set to DataRow.  Or you could use a LINQ statement to bring back only rows with a RowType == DataRow and loop over that.

**UPDATE**  Here is a quick sample of what I meant.  But in reviewing your code it does not appear that you have any text in the second cell of your gridview, in fact your gridview only has one cell based on the code you provided.

```
public void Dedupe(Object o, EventArgs e)
{
    String output = "start ";
    IEnumerable<GridViewRow> rows = from r in GV0.Rows
                                    where r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow
                                    select r;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            output += row.Cells[1];
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = output;
}
```

Comment: I think I know what you mean. row is of type GridViewRow at the moment. I tried to parse it using: row = (DataRow)row; but it won't let me. Could this be the reason that I am getting empty strings?